# Re-apply layout_centerHorizontal programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom relative layout view, where I have to dynamically change the background resource. The problem is, after setting the background, the layout_centerHorizontal property of its children are removed and the items are no longer horizontally centered. I am trying to figure out how to re-apply it. Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/marker_background"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:background="@drawable/ic_markerdefault"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/marker_category"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_bike"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/marker_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/marker_category"
    tools:text="$10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="@style/MarkerPriceText"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code:

```
private ImageView mImgCategory;
private TextView mTextPrice;
...

private void setBackground(int state) {


    switch (state) {
        case DEFAULT:
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_markerdefault);
            break;
        case ACTIVE:
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_markerselected);
            break;
        case VISITED:
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_markervisited);
            break;
        default:
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_markerdefault);
            break;
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) mImgCategory.getLayoutParams();
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, TRUE);
    mImgCategory.setLayoutParams(lp);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = (LayoutParams) mTextPrice.getLayoutParams();
    lp2.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL, TRUE);
    mTextPrice.setLayoutParams(lp2);
}

....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change layout_width and layout_height to "match_parent"